# Single Instance of a WebForm per Session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

What I could use to solve the problem: **C#**, **ASP.NET**, **Javascript**.

2 Webpages: **Index.aspx** - **Work.aspx**.

**Index.aspx**: Stadistics and info about the work they're going to do once they hit the link that redirects them to Work.aspx.

**Work.aspx**: Start working with clients.

So, what I need to accomplish is a single instance of Work.aspx. Because while they are working with Work.aspx, Index.aspx is still open (they need to research data and stuff), but if they hit the link for Work.aspx they get to open another instance and that's not what I want.

I don't know what's the best way for accomplishing this since all Ive found on Mutex is based on winforms. (if it happens to be that you have some link with info for handling mutex in a webform then I may be able to start there, but I havent found that yet)

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT.**
Work.aspx is a popup, so employees have both webforms open at the same time.

Comment: You need single instance per user, or single instance globally?

Comment: Every employee needs one, They dont have to be allowed to open another one (work on 2 clients at a time)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're trying to say. Do you mean you want to open a popup in stead of a redirect? Are you talking about a single user his interactions or a group? Aspx pages are created whenever a client requests them, you can't have a single instance of them, they live for a few seconds and get parsed into html which then sits in the ram of your client's browser.

Comment: Do you need work.aspx to open always in the same popup? Use html `target="work"` in your link to work.aspx

Comment: @Kristof thanks, I did some editing. 2nd webpage is actually a popup. It comes from a redirect(using ex. methods)

Comment: @DanielSh how are you planning to determine if user has ended his work on this or that client?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Once they finish working on a client, employees can activate 2 controls. "End client, give me another" and "client ended, let me out of the system". If they log out of work.aspx and after a break they want to start all over again, they go to index.aspx and start again.

Comment: @DanielSh. then you just code your `work.aspx` so that it always returns data for current client in work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you might try using the [Hyperlink.Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx) property to always open Work.aspx in the same named window.

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ... NavigateUrl="Work.aspx" Target="work" ... />
```

**Update in response to comment**

> they trigger a few things in order to populate Work.aspx with the info they need ...

What you need to do is "remember" the state of Work.aspx server-side, e.g. by storing state data in `Session` (or somewhere else: e.g. a database).  Then each time Work.aspx is requested, render a version with the appropriate state.

> What I can think of right now is: When they open work.aspx for the first time. Set a Session variable to true. And every next time they hit START-WORKING again, check that session variable beforehand to know **if they are allowed or not**. Were you refering to something like this Joe?

I think they should always be "allowed" to open a new Work.aspx.  After all, the user may have closed the previous Work.aspx window, and you won't know about this server-side.  You should always allow the user to "start working" - but display Work.aspx with the most recent state, which you've saved somewhere server-side (e.g. Session).

Comment: don't think it'll work. When they hit the link in index.aspx for opening work.aspx they trigger a few things in order to populate Work.aspx with the info they need. So, if WORK.aspx is opened, I need not to trigger anything if they hit the link on index.aspx.

Comment: @DanielSh so use session flag or add "LastRequest" field to the users table and check it.

Comment: What I can think of right now is: When they open work.aspx for the first time. Set a Session variable to true. And every next time they hit START-WORKING again, check that session variable beforehand to know if they are allowed or not. Were you refering to something like this Joe?

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the insight, seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

There is not and can be no way of doing this. Web-applications are essentially stateless, and each interaction with user consists of separate request-response pair. asp.net creates new instance of web form for each request, uses it to process request and deletes it afterwards.

So what precisely would you need that for? In most cases there can be more than one page, but still same data.

Comment: Work.aspx is the web used by employees to work on their respectives cases. If they hit START-WORKING on index.aspx 10 times, they will have 10 WORK.aspx webforms. I just want them to have 1. Hope I make myself clear.

Comment: @DanielSh. you **can't** do that. All you can do is return some other content on every subsequent call to `work.aspx`, but you'll have troubles with determining when user *is* allowed to do work, and when he/she *is not*.